# Standard input state after error condition

Tags: c++, iostream

The following code snippet is taken from `C++ Iostreams Handbook by Steve Teale`.  It suggests invoking cin in an endless loop so that the user is continuously prompted for the correct input, and only when the correct input is entered do we exit the loop.

This code snippet works correctly but I am confused by the `if(cin){...}` statement.  I would have expected something like `if(!cin.fail()){...}`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin.unsetf(ios::skipws);
  // turn off whitespece skipping
  
  cout << "Enter a value for n, followed by [Enter]: " << flush;
  
  for(;;) {
    cin >> n;
    if(cin) { //cin is in good state; input was ok
      cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
                // flush away the unwanted
                // newline character
      break;
    }

    // Poster's comment (not from the author)
    // In this section of the code cin has evaluated to false
    //
    cin.clear(); // clear the error state
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
                 // get rid of garbage characters
    cout << "That was no good, try again: " << flush;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Q) How does cin evaluate to false (i.e. a zero or null value) in the event of a failure?**

cin is an object, not a pointer that could be set to null.  Furthermore, in the section of code where cin evaluates to false we can still invoke member functions like `clear` and `ignore`.

Comment: They have just reversed the logic. The loop is a continual read-loop that breaks only when good input is received. That is a fine way to do it. Note: the `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');` cleans up after the good input in case there were any extraneous characters following the read of integer `n`, e.g. `"4 and other stuff"`. Which is also good practice.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how does cin evaluate to False?  Kindly shed some light on that.

Comment: Any time there is an error, (e.g. `badbit` or `failbit` set), the stream state will evaluate `false` whether you check `if (cin)` or `if (cin.good())`. In both cases if an error bit is set the condition is `false`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is there some operator overload magic at work that allows cin to be used in a boolean context (in the `if` statement)?   There seems to something more than meets my eye.  Kindly point me to some link and I will enlighten myself accordingly.

Comment: See [std::basic_ios::operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and [std::ios_base::iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). It will test `true` on `goodbit` or `eofbit`, `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing is a result of inheritance and implicit conversion. More specifically, `std::cin` has an `operator bool()` that converts the state of the stream to a boolean and that operator returns `!fail()`.

`std::cin` is a global [`std::basic_istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) provided by the standard lib, and `basic_istream` inherits from [`std::basic_ios`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) which defines the function `operator bool()`

The chain of inheritance is:

```
std::ios_base <-- std::basic_ios <-- std::basic_istream
```

You may find the table at the bottom of [this webpage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) useful to compare `operator bool()` to the other state checking functions of the stream and the streams' different status flags.